# How can i use lxml xpath to get specific element from web scraping data

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I followed the link below to scrape historical data from Prize Zombie:

> https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

The script I have is like below:

```
import requests  
import pandas as pd
import sys    
import csv  
import urllib2  
import sys  
import time  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit() 

url = 'https://www.pricezombie.com/viewproduct/pF/5jNvj/Align-Probiotic-Supplement-42-count'

r = Render(url)  

result = r.frame.toHtml()

formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)
```

According the author, now I need to use xpath to get the element I want.
However, I really can't figure out how to get those specific elements from the tree.

The html part should look like this:

```
class="pt1">$27.51, May 15 - Jun 10
```

And the information I need is:

```
<g class="pzmo">
    <rect x="91" y="14" height="216" width="7" style="fill:#ccc" fill-opacity="0.2"></rect>
    <rect fill-opacity="0.9" class="prec" x="98" y="14" width="170" height="20"></rect>
    <text x="103" y="28" class="pt1">$27.51, May 15 - Jun 10</text>
</g>
```

Could anyone tell me what's the xpath for that?

Comment: You can open the page with Chrome, right click, "Inspect element", find the element you want in the Elements tab, right click the element and "Copy XPath".

Comment: @multivac Thank you so much! I'm really new to XPath. I tried to get the XPath and it looks like this :"//*[@id="chart3Dqt"]/svg/g[269]/text[1]". The only thing changes is just the number in g[ ] (e.g., 269). Do you know how can I set that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath is, for example:

```
//*[@id="chart3Dqt"]/svg/g[412]/text[1]
```

If you want to vary the index you can substitute with a formatting field:

```
>>> xpath = '//*[@id="chart3Dqt"]/svg/g[{index}]/text[1]'

>>> xpath.format(index=412)
//*[@id="chart3Dqt"]/svg/g[412]/text[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really new to XPath. I got the same kind of xpath. The only thing changes every time is just the number in g[ ] (e.g., 412). Do you know how can I set that part?

Comment: I mean I need the price and data value (and only when class="pt1"). How can I use that xpath with lxml etree?

Comment: I don't really know much about `xpath` and `lxml`. That would be another question if you can't find an answer in [the **`lxml`** documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text) or elsewhere on this site.

Comment: If it is not necessary for you to use lxml I would recommend you to use BeautifulSoup. I find xpath a bit arcane, but the syntax of BeautifulSoup is very easy, and it also has the possibility of selecting nodes using css selectors. Also it is an html parser, so it should parse html with errors better than lxml.

Comment: @dyeray Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I tried BeautifulSoup first. The reason for me to choose lxml is because the website to scrape has javascript implementation. When I use BeautifulSoup, I can only get part of the html. Do you know how BeautifulSoup works for JavaScript rendered webpages?

Comment: Do you mean lxml runs the javascript to modify the dom tree? I am not sure I understand what you mean... In any case, BeautifulSoup can be ran using lxml in the background, like this `tree = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml")`, so I think, at least in this case, it should build the same tree.
But I think, to have the tree modified by javascript you need to use a browser engine, for example you can use selenium for this.

Comment: @dyeray I don't think this is related to our answer here (c: